# Hyperledger Fabric on production

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

For the past couple of month we are planning to build an application using Hyperledger Fabric framework which can further be deployed in production. We initially started using Composer to create BNA. We were successful in deploying the BNA locally and were able to build a basic prototype. But now we need to move the application on production sevrer where there are VMs. We tried deploying the same BNA there but could not do it and got many errors.

We then moved to Node.js SDK for any luck but there also we got many errors and have not been able to finally do it. Can anyone share any tutorials/points to consider/steps for taking Hyperledger Fabric application to production.

We are tool agnostic. Both Composer and Node.js suggestion are welcome.

**Note: We require multiple peers on multiple VMs/hosts.**

Answer (score 1):

Could you specify the error for multiple VMs/hosts?
When I tried run fabric/composer multiple peers on single VM(both GCP/AWS), there was no error. I am not tried for multiple VMs, but I believe if you use extra_hosts configuration, it would be same.